# Posting to page wall as admin by Graph Api requires manage_pages permission too

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

One of my client's website, i coded so that user's of his page can post from his website using Graph Api.Posting is done this way -

```
FB.login(function(response) {
   if (response.status=='connected') {
     if (response.authResponse.accessToken) 
     {
        var token = response.authResponse.accessToken;      
        FB.api('/'+jQuery("#input_id_storing_pageid").val()+'/feed?access_token='+token+'&message='+jQuery("#message_input_box").val(), 'POST', function(response)                            {
          if (!response || response.error) {                 
              alert('Error: You are not allowed to post '+ response.error.message);     
          } else { /*do other tasks */ }
       });
     } else { /* show alert messages */ }
 } else { /* show alert messages */ }
}, {scope:'publish_stream' });
```

It was posting well before but now page admin can't post, getting error-

> "(#283) Requires extended permission: manage_pages OAuthException".

Any non-admin user posting going well, but not by some page admin users who have manager role for the page. I tested using graph api explorer but same error I am getting.

Fyi the application by which posting done by graph api has `October 2013 migration` enabled, but I don't think it has this new requirement that page admin need to have `manage_pages` permission as well as `publish_stream` permission to post to page wall, cause I asked client to disable that setting for testing. So where went wrong?

Comment: Posting _as_ the page requires a page access token (and to get that, `manage_pages`). But if you just want the users to post as themselves, that should work without `manage_pages`, even if the user is an admin of that page. If it doesn’t, I’d say this is worth filing a bug: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs

Comment: exactly a bug as before when admin of the page posted they did not require additional "manage_pages" permission, only publish_stream was  enough.but now admin users are not allowed to post to page wall without additional manage_pages permission.